# Python infinite loop check processes and do an action

Tags: python, loops, process

I'm trying to find if a certain process is running, if its not running then go to a specific folder and open a random file in it so it can start running. Ex: Check all processes to see if vlc.exe is running, if not running go to this folder ('name of folder') and pick a random file from there and open it (start playing file). I want it to be done infinitely not just once meaning it will constantly check if vlc.exe is running, if it is running print the process name (vlc.exe) or if the vlc.exe isn't running go to this folder ('name of folder') and pick a random file from there and open it (start playing file).

```
import psutil, os, random, webbrowser

substring_check = "Empty"

dummy_check = "Yes"

for proc in psutil.process_iter():

    if 'vlc' in proc.name():

        substring_check = ("Yes")

        print(proc.name())

        print(substring_check)

if substring_check.find(dummy_check):

    basedir = "C:\\Users\\"
    # Chooses a random file from folder
    file = random.choice([x for x in os.listdir(basedir) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(basedir, x))])
    # Prints file that is picked
    print("Playing file {}...".format(file))

    # Open file that was picked
    webbrowser.open(os.path.join(basedir, file))
```

I tried this but it only works once and it shuts off, it doesn't do it infinitely

Comment: What did you do to try and "do it infinitely"?

Comment: Perhaps you need a while loop?

Comment: How do I insert a while loop in my code so that it includes all parts, I tried while true: pass and it didn’t work :(.

Comment: Have a look at [while loops here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop). As @ScottHunter mentioned, try out something and if you encounter any problems, you can edit your question to get help.

Comment: I'm not familiar with what you're trying to achieve but perhaps you need something like ```
is_flag = True
while is_flag:
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
 bla bla bla
```

Also maybe use an else condition to break your loop by changing `is_flag = False` if certain conditions aren't met.

Comment: Just put everything except the `import` line inside `while True:`

Comment: And learn to use boolean variables rather than strings.

Comment: `vlc_found = any('vlc' in proc.name() for proc in psutil.process_iter())`

Comment: Thank you and everyone that contributed, I finally got it to work correctly.